# Read RAID disks on another RAID adapter

Tags: raid, adaptec

I have a server with a failed motherbord.
The motherboard has an embeeded Adaptec RAID controler.
The server has 3 SCSI disks in a software RAID5 array (so the RAID controller is used only as a SCSI controler, not RAID).

I want to connect the 3 disks on another machine with an Adaptec RAID controler (I only have this machine available).

Usually, when we use a RAID controler, we have to initialise the disks. So the data will be erased. Even if we only want direct access to the disks.

Is there a way to use a RAID controler without any disk initiation ?
I think this heavily depend on the manufacturer, firmware, etc.

Comment: In the Adaptec RAID Setup utility (the one you can enter during boot), it is possible to create Arrays (and JBODs) with `skip initialisation`. It will warn you, but this is most useful e.g. if you need to restore a failed array. It should be appropriate in your case. Don't expect the controller to get this running as a RAID5, though. Go for JBOD and restore the software RAID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Adaptec controllers should expose disks without Adaptec raid label as JBOD by default. (Disclaimer: untested)